# PhantomJS (CentOS) draws circles not smoothly on Acrobat Reader

Tags: javascript, css, pdf, phantomjs, rasterize

When using PhantomJS on CentOS I have a kind of weired Problem. On each PDF I create with the rasterize.js I have circles, which will be drawn pixelated in the pdf if viewing with the Acrobat Reader, but it will look good on the Google Chrome PDF Viewer.

I have set up a zoom scale in the css with 0.86 on the page itself and also tried a branch of PhantomJS which allows to set dpi, which only resizes the elements of the webpage. What i really need, I guess, is to set up the dpi for the print version? Or to resize something, but I don't know what.

Here is what it looks like on the Acrobat Reader

> [image: AR]

And here it is how it looks like on the Google Chrome PDF Viewer

> [image]

But zooming inside the PDF to the specific dot, both look similar. On what does it depend on.

Comment: Please share a sample PDF.

Comment: sorry, I can't, it contains sensitive data

Comment: I doubt a circle is sensitive data. And you said that *you* create the PDFs. Thus, it should be possible for you to create a PDF with such a circle but without sensitive data.